# Is there a way to generate same encrypted value while encrypting same text using aes 256?

Tags: encryption, aes, aes-gcm, block-cipher, badpaddingexception

I have a requirement of of encrypt and decrypt the text but each time the encryption value of same text should be generated same.

Suppose if I am encrypting a text "My Name is John". And while encrypting first time its value was generated `kPddYx+eLwgK6CkJK1Vt2iGP8x8dv66YKz8YoHmfhrQ=` then requirement is, if I am again encrypting the same text  "My Name is John", It should generate the same encrypted string as the first one.

Comment: Use the same key every time?

Comment: Many encryptions add a really random _seed_ to generate a key. Providing the same seed would then ensure the same encryption. However that would often open some ways of attack, like with prefixes of the text. For a non-productive encryption you could use `text.hashCode()` as int seed.

Comment: @derpirscher Yes using the same key everytime

Comment: Well obviously you are not. If you are encrypting the same block of data with the same key, you will get the same result. Because, especially for a symmetric algorithm, how would you else be able to decrypt your data again? But as you don't show any code, nobody will be able to help you  any further. The only advice one can give on that amout of information is: *Use the same key every time for encryption*

Comment: @derpirscher I have added sample code

Comment: The old XY problem popping up again.

Comment: Yes, but don't do it. The randomness of the ciphertext at constant key and plaintext is caused by a random IV and is intentional for security reasons. `Cipher#init()` generates a random IV each time (which can be retrieved with `getIV()`). Alternatively, a random IV can be explicitly generated and passed into `init()`. If a constant IV is applied here, this would result in a constant ciphertext, which is a common bug.

Comment: @Topaco common bug?

Comment: @kelalaka - Well, yes, taking a static IV is what I would call a bug. And this happens quite often.

Comment: @Topaco isn't this necessary for testing and verification?

Comment: @kelalaka - I'm referring to the *finished* implementation, this should not contain a static IV. For testing purposes this is OK.